# "enableScene() does not exist" -- Troubles with SimpleOpenNi and Processing

Tags: kinect, processing, simple-openni

Im' trying to make an app with processing using kinect, and SimpleOpenNi. I tried to follow this tutorial http://www.creativeapplications.net/processing/kinect-physics-tutorial-for-processing/ , but i'm stuck at the very beginning : when i launch the first script processing returns me this error :
"The function enableScene() does not exist"
Also, the function sceneImage() doen't work.
I installed KinectSDK, OpenNi, NiTe, SimpleOpenNi lib, tried on 3 differents versions of processing (1.5.1, 2.0.1 x86, 2.0.2 x64) with win7&win8. I really can't find any solution on the web, if someone have some any clue, i'd be glad ! 
Thanks !

Comment: what version of SimpleOpenNI are you using ?

Answer (score 2):

Change `enableScene()` to `isInit()` and replace `draw()` with

```
void draw() {
  // update the SimpleOpenNI object
  context.update();
  image(context.rgbImage(), 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of SimpleOpenNI are you using? The most recent addition to my knowledge lacks the enableScene() method. Use the wayback machine and download an earlier version.